# PHP XMPP Pre-binding

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-4, xmpp

I have reading tutorials, mailing lists, and other resources to understand how pre-binding actually works. I have found a few pre-bind scripts with PHP, used it, successfully got the `jid, rid, sid` but session always gets lost on page refresh.

I do the prebind on log in, then set the `rid, jid, sid` into a session cookie.

After logging in the prebind was successful. I am able to send messages. But on page reload the connection gets lost.

I have understood that on every request the RID must increment I have already coded that the rid cookie adds 1 on every refresh. But I just wanted to ask, do I have to pre-bind on every refresh? or only on log in?

I have seen a few example scripts that binds every page reload. I cannot do a pre-bind on each page reload because I cannot remember the password, nor can I save the password somewhere in the cookie to remember (because that's a security issue).

So, how does pre-binding really work? I am using openfire as a xmpp server.

This is the code on my login

```
$xmppPrebind = new XmppPrebind('xxxx', $bosh_url, 'xxxx', false);
$xmppPrebind->connect($user->username, $password);
$xmppPrebind->auth();
$sessionInfo = $xmppPrebind->getSessionInfo(); // array containing sid, rid and jid
Session::put('bosh_url', $bosh_url);
Session::put('bosh_jid', $sessionInfo['jid']);
Session::put('bosh_sid', $sessionInfo['sid']);
Session::put('bosh_rid', $sessionInfo['rid']);
```

After authenticating the user successfully I also log him/her in to the openfire server.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I just wrote my own XMPP server in Node.JS using the node-xmpp library. Then wrote the client also in javascript then I had a seamless integration for it. @DevZer0

Comment: Any plans to share it with us :)

Comment: Did you find any solution @majidarif

Comment: Wrote my own server with nodexmpp

Comment: I asked a question related to this here-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311205/invalid-challenge-response-received-while-using-xmpp-prebind-php-master please help.